# Error 404 since we update the security certificate domain

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

We are making a hybrid app with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. By making Ajax requests to an external server we retrieves some data in JSON format.

We have never had any problems (IOS and Android). Since we updated the domain security certificate  ( we are forced to the signature algorithm is RSA SHA -256 encryption ) , we are getting 404 error  in Ajax response. A day before with  SHA1 signature certificate there was no problem . In contrast IOS still give us any problems.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks for the help.